# Why does this Python script create an infinite loop? (recursion)

Tags: python, recursion, stack-overflow

Why/how does this create a seemingly infinite loop? Incorrectly, I assumed this would cause some form of a stack overflow type error.

```
i = 0

def foo () :
    global i

    i += 1
    try :
        foo()
    except RuntimeError :
        # This call recursively goes off toward infinity, apparently.
        foo()

foo()

print i
```

Comment: Well, you just keep on calling `foo`, with no stopping condition, so it will continue to recurse forever. And even when you get an exception, you recurse _again_.

Comment: Shouldn't Python run out of memory or something? Or is the call stack cleared after the `RuntimeError`?

Comment: Possibly python is optimizing it into iteration

Comment: @RectangleTangle you should use just `return` in except statement not `return foo()`, see my solution below.

Comment: @Blorgbeard no, Python does not do recursion optimization.

Comment: Wonder why there're so little subscribers to the `stackoverflow` tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you change the code to

```
i = 0
def foo ():
    global i
    i += 1
    print i
    try :
        foo()
    except RuntimeError :
        # This call recursively goes off toward infinity, apparently.
        foo()
    finally:
        i -= 1
        print i

foo()
```

You'll observe that the output oscillates short below 999 (1000 being Python's default recursion limit). That means, when the limit is hit (`RuntimeError`) that last call of `foo()` is terminated, and another one is set off to replace it immediately.

If you raise a `KeyboardInterrupt` you'll observe how the entire trace is being terminated at once.

---

**UPDATE**

Interestingly the second call of `foo()` is not protected by the `try ... except`-block anymore. Therefore the application will in fact terminate eventually. This becomes apparant if you set the recursion limit to a smaller number, e.g. the output for `sys.setrecursionlimit(3)`:

```
$ python test.py
1
2
1
2
1
0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 19, in <module>
    foo()
  File "test.py", line 14, in foo
    foo()
  File "test.py", line 14, in foo
    foo()
RuntimeError
```

Answer (score 6):

The `RuntimeError` exception will be raised if the recursion limit is exceeded.

Since you're catching this exception, your machine is going to continue on, but you're only adding to a single global int value, which doesn't use much memory.

You can set the recursion limit with `sys.setrecursionlimit()`.
The current limit can be found with `sys.getrecursionlimit()`.

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.setrecursionlimit(100)
>>>
>>> def foo(i):
...     i += 1
...     foo(i)
...
>>> foo(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in foo
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
>>>
```

If you want to run out of memory try consuming more of it.

```
>>> def foo(l):
...     l = l * 100
...     foo(l)
...
>>> foo(["hello"])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in foo
MemoryError
>>>
```